# React Native - stuck on launch screen ios simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, launch-screen

I tested my app on iOS simulator, the build was fine but while running the app, **it gets stuck in the LaunchScreen** and the following errors are shown in the console.

```
> Task <A744A8BE-D248-4DF7-ADA6-AA7D35EAECFD>.<3> finished with error
> [-1003] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the
> specified hostname could not be found."
> UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000dd24f0 {Error
> Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)"
> UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}},
> NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasedynamiclinks-ipv6.googleapis.com/v1/installAttribution?key=AIzaSyCjo1EX5gvRSzEwVRd-hodSpHSpvLe-Dic,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasedynamiclinks-ipv6.googleapis.com/v1/installAttribution?key=AIzaSyCjo1EX5gvRSzEwVRd-hodSpHSpvLe-Dic,
> _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not
> be found.} 2020-08-25 21:57:36.095421+0530 [54728:756954]
> [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid
> 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} 2020-08-25
> 21:57:36.095478+0530[54728:757370] [Client] Updating
> selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The
> connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} 2020-08-25
> 21:57:36.095717+0530[54728:757370] [Client] Updating
> selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid
> 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} 2020-08-25
> 21:57:36.096341+0530[54728:756954] [Client] Synchronous
> remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
> Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} 2020-08-25
> 21:57:36.096398+0530[54728:757370] [Client] Updating
> selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The
> connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} 2020-08-25
> 21:57:36.098339+0530[54728:756954] [Client] Synchronous
> remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
> Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} 2020-08-25
> 21:57:36.098431+0530[54728:757370] [Client] Updating
> selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The
> connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} 2020-08-25
> 21:57:36.100020+0530[54728:757370] [Client] Updating
> selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The
> connection to service on pid 2020-08-25 21:57:36.100447+0530
>[54728:757066] ERROR: HTTP Request (OSRequestRegisterUser)
> must contain app_id parameter 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} 2020-08-25
> 21:57:36.108779+0530[54728:757066] Request
> <OSRequestRegisterUser: 0x600000d341e0> fail result error Error
> Domain=OneSignalError Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={error=HTTP Request
> (OSRequestRegisterUser) must contain app_id parameter} 2020-08-25
> 21:57:36.108785+0530[54728:757370] [Client] Updating
> selectors after delegate removal failed with: Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid
> 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named
> com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.} 2020-08-25
> 21:57:36.108958+0530[54728:756621] ERROR: Encountered error
> during push registration with OneSignal: Error Domain=OneSignalError
> Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={error=HTTP Request (OSRequestRegisterUser)
> must contain app_id parameter} 2020-08-25 21:57:36.109064+0530
>[54728:756621] ERROR: Encountered error during email
> registration with OneSignal: (null)
```

the android version of the app works fine.
My xcode version is 11.3.1.
In the Edit Scheme of xcode, I have set the environment variable `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE=disable` after going through some of the stackoverflow queries.

Can anyone help to sort this issue?